# const typedef; in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, constants, typedef

What was the original reason behind allowing statements like the following in C and C++?

```
const typedef;
```

It doesn't seem to make any practical sense.

Also, you can do this: `const;` and `typedef;`

Edit: @AndreyT points out it is not a standard defined behavior. For the full answer, I would like to know about any possible advantages that arose in front of GCC devs when they decided this type of code should be compilable.

Comment: If I was Linus Torvalds, I'd say: "In C, its sole purpose is to keep C++ programmers out."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a degenerate form of declaration.

In C declaration is not a statement. It is a declaration. And what you have above is not allowed.

> **6.7 Declarations**
>
> 2 A declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the
> parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a
> tag, or the members of an enumeration.

In C++ declaration is a statement. But still what you have above is not allowed. From C++03

> **7 Declarations**
>
> 3 In a simple-declaration, the optional init-declarator-list can be
> omitted only when declaring a class (clause 9) or enumeration (7.2),
> that is, when the decl-specifier-seq contains either a
> class-specifier, an elaborated type-specifier with a class-key (9.1),
> or an enum-specifier.

If some compiler allows this in C or C++ code, it must be a quirk of that compiler. You should direct that question to its authors.

As you probably know, the syntax of C and C++ is not specified by the grammar alone. Doing it by the grammar alone would be too complicated or downright impossible. Some additional restrictions are imposed by the text that accompanies the grammar. Compilers usually treat the grammar itself with respect, but when it comes to those elaborate additional restrictions... many compilers allows some violations to slip through.

I would make an educated guess that this must be a side-effect of the "empty declaration" extension. Since the beginning of times empty declarations were illegal in C and C++. For example, this code has always been illegal

```
void foo() {}; // In file scope
```

because it follows function definition with an empty declaration. However, virtually all compilers accepted it, allowing empty declarations as an extension. For the very same reason you could write

```
;;;; // In file scope
```

in the middle of the file and have your code compile. What you have in your example is also an empty declaration, into which you added some inconsequential qualifiers and storage-class specifiers.

P.S. Correct me if I'm wrong, but C++11 legalized empty declarations. I'm not sure about C11.

Comment: On a side note, both `gcc` and `clang` seem to allow this (only emit a warning) with `-Wall -ansi -std=c89 -pedantic`.

Comment: @sasha.sochka: Careful with the terminology! Empty *statement* is and has always been legal in C and C++. Empty *declaration* is(was) illegal in "classic" C and C++.

Comment: The _empty-declaration_ legalized in C++11 is the grammatical entity containing one token `;`.  So `const typedef;` and such things are still illegal.

Comment: Does this answer imply that `while(true) ;` is not compilable by pre C++11 standards?

Comment: @sasha.sochka Do you understand what **In file scope** means, or have you just ignored those essential words?

Comment: @JimBalter, finally got it. Just ignored. I'm not very attentive today - just answered a question and later discovered that the actual question was very different from what I answered.

Comment: @sasha.sochka: Since in C++ local declarations are *statements*, it is impossible to create an empty declaration in local scope. It will simply be interpreted as an empty *statement*. And empty statements are perfectly legal. For this reason in local scope you can always legally write `;;;;;` or `while (true);`. In order to form an empty *declaration* in C++ you have to place it somewhere where statements are not allowed. For example, in namespace scope (file scope) or in class scope.

Comment: I'd thought the empty statements were allowed so that you could leave out sections in a for loop to handle them internally, e.g.: `for(;i < 100; i++)` or `for(i = 0; i < 100;)` or even just `for(;;)` which I've seen occasionally.

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman: While it is indeed allowed, it has nothing to do with empty statements. The entire `for` construct is a statement, but the individual sections in the `for` header are not statements. Leaving them empty is allowed by dedicated portions of `for` specification, not by the general possibility to use empty statements. Empty statements is what let's you write cycles like `for (i = 0;i < 100; i++);` (i.e. with `;` immediately after the closing brace).